# How to move an Object with an Angle?

Tags: javascript, html

I wont to move my Object(has {x:10,y:15}) with an angle off 20°
Exmaple PIC: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/591642374376259593/602618211040493568/unknown.png

```
let plus = {
   x: Math.cos(this.angel),
   y: Math.sin(this.angel)
}
this.x += plus.x
this.y += plus.y
```

I expect an velocity like {x:2.5,y:3}

Comment: `angle` or `angel`?

Comment: Can you add which output you get, and which output you expected instead, providing all relevant variables in your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
let angle = 20;
```

You need to convert angle into radians

```
let radians = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
```

Then use that to find x and y

```
let plus = {
   x: Math.cos(radians),
   y: Math.sin(radians)
}

this.x += plus.x
this.y += plus.y
```

The angle 0 degree is at 3 o'clock and 90 degree is 6 o'clock and so on.

If you want the angle in the drawing then

```
let angle = 90 - 20;
```